# How to get duplicates in a JavaScript Array using Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array for which I need to the items that are duplicates and print the items based on a specific property. I know how to get the unique items using underscore.js but I need to find the duplicates instead of the unique values

```
var somevalue=[{name:"john",country:"spain"},{name:"jane",country:"spain"},{name:"john",country:"italy"},{name:"marry",country:"spain"}]


var uniqueList = _.uniq(somevalue, function (item) {
        return item.name;
    })
```

This returns:

```
[{name:"jane",country:"spain"},{name:"marry",country:"spain"}]
```

but I actually need the opposite

```
[{name:"john",country:"spain"},{name:"john",country:"italy"}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use .filter() and .where() for source array by values from uniq array and getting duplicate items.

```
var uniqArr = _.uniq(somevalue, function (item) {
    return item.name;
});

var dupArr = [];
somevalue.filter(function(item) {
    var isDupValue = uniqArr.indexOf(item) == -1;

    if (isDupValue)
    {
        dupArr = _.where(somevalue, { name: item.name });
    }
});

console.log(dupArr);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8L6n504/4/)

**Updated** 
Second way if you have more than one duplicate item, and more clean code.

```
var dupArr = [];
var groupedByCount = _.countBy(somevalue, function (item) {
    return item.name;
});

for (var name in groupedByCount) {
    if (groupedByCount[name] > 1) {
        _.where(somevalue, {
            name: name
        }).map(function (item) {
            dupArr.push(item);
        });
    }
};
```

[Look fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8L6n504/5/)

Comment: Your fiddle is pretty much broken

Comment: why? look in console log

Comment: The request was for the dup items

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I needed and very cool way too. Thanks a lot Igor.

Answer (score 14):

A purely underscore based approach is:

```
_.chain(somevalue).groupBy('name').filter(function(v){return v.length > 1}).flatten().value()
```

This would produce an array of all duplicate, so each duplicate will be in the output array as many times as it is duplicated. If you only want 1 copy of each duplicate, you can simply add a `.uniq()` to the chain like so:

```
_.chain(somevalue).groupBy('name').filter(function(v){return v.length > 1}).uniq().value()
```

No idea how this performs, but I do love my one liners... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here how I have done the same thing:

`_.keys(_.pick(_.countBy(somevalue, b=> b.name), (value, key, object) => value > 1))`

Answer (score 0):

```
var somevalue=[{name:"john",country:"spain"},{name:"jane",country:"spain"},{name:"john",country:"italy"},{name:"marry",country:"spain"}];
var uniqueList = _.uniq(somevalue, function (item) {return item.country;})
```

*//from this you will get the required output*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Correction to [chmac's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32709647/6761483) answer.

```
_.chain(somevalue).groupBy('name').filter(function(v){return v.length > 1}).flatten().uniq().value()
```

The values need to be flattened before using unique function